# two select options in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two select options but i found little complication between them in the javascript.
here is my javascript code :

```
  function displayVals() {
     var singleValues = $("select option:selected").text(); //to stay slected
    $("#hiddenselect").val(singleValues);                   //hidden field of second select option
    $("samp").html("" + singleValues);             // this to insert text between samp tags
  $("select > option:first").prop("disabled", "disabled") // this to disable first option
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function() {
        displayVals();
    });
    displayVals();

    $("select#menucompare").change(function() {
        $("#aform").submit();                   // second select options to submit

    });
      $("select#infmenu").change(function() {
        $("#infform").submit();                 // first select options to submit 

    });        
});
```

now what i expect is :
- only the first select options ( the first option is disabled), need the second select option also (the first option be disabled)

here is my html code
my first select option :

```
    <form action="" id="infform" method="post">
        <select id="infmenu" name ="infmenu" size="1" class="select" onchange="submitinfform()" >
       <option value="0" >Please Select your country</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $row9['id'] ;?>" <?php if ($_SESSION['infmenu'] == $row9['id']) { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> ><?php echo $row9['name'] ;?></option><?php  } ?>
      </select>
     <input type="hidden" name="hiddenselect" value="<?php echo $infmenu;  ?>" />
   </form>
```

this the second select options

```
    <form id="aform" method="post">
     <select id="menucompare" name ="menucompare" size="1" class="select" onchange="submitaform()">
         <option value="0">Select one</option>
         <option value="west" <?php if ($menucompare == "west") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >West</option>
         <option value="est" <?php   if ($menucompare == "est") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >Est</option>

    </select>
         <input type="hidden" name="hiddenselect" value="<?php echo $menucompare ;  ?>" />  

</form>
```

i have spent on this many days no luck
thanks for your time

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't really understand what you're asking here. You need to clean up the question a bit, grammatically.

Comment: edited my quesstion but i dont know if its clear now , sorry for my english its not so good

Comment: No problem, I wasn't trying to be mean, just was struggling to understand what you needed help with :)

Answer (score 2):

Not able to understand you code well. Here is little help for you to try:

To get selected value (value attribute) of the first select element use:

```
$("#infmenu").val();
```

To get selected value (value attribute) of the first select element use:

```
$("#menucompare").val();
```

To disable first option in first select called "infmenu":

```
$("option", "#infmenu").first().attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To disable first option in second select called "infmenu":

```
$("option", "#menucompare").first().attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To get displayed text of the first select element use:

```
$("option:selected", "#infmenu").text();
```

To get displayed text of the second select element use:

```
$("option:selected", "#menucompare").text();
```

Comment: i want disable the first option in both select elements called "infmenu" and "menucompare"

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery selector that you're using is `$("select option:selected")`. This means "find all `<option>` tags that are selected and are children of a `<select>` element."

You have two `<select>` elements, so your selector is matching both of them. If you want to match a specific one, you'll need to refine your selector. Since you already have an ID attribute on the second one, try using `$("#menucompare option:selected")`.

**Change:**

```
var singleValues = $("select option:selected").text(); //to stay slected
```

**To:**

```
var singleValues = $("#menucompare option:selected").text(); //to stay slected
```

Comment: it fixed the text to appear , now it appear text only from second , good , but it miss the first problem , is the second select options (the first select option is still enabled) this `$("select > option:first").prop("disabled", "disabled")` it disable only the first select options , i want also the dropdown select options to be disabled the first option

Comment: it fixed the text to appear , now it appear text only from second , good , but it miss the first problem  is : the second select elements (the first select option is still enabled) this `$("select > option:first").prop("disabled", "disabled")` it disable only the first option in first select elements , i want also to be disabled in first option of second select elements . thx

Comment: `$("select > option:first)` should select the first <option> element that is a direct child of a <select> element. This should match the first <option> element of **both** of your <select> elements. If it's not working for you like that, I couldn't tell you why.

Comment: no its not working , it disable only in the first select elements,

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but try using just `$("select option:first")` or `$("select:first-child")`.

Comment: If all else fails try `$("#infmenu > option:first, #menucompare > option:first")`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to choose the second select tag. so you have to change your *jquery selector* in line 2:

```
var singleValues = $("select:nth-child(2) option:selected").text();
```

Comment: it fixed the text to appear , now it appear text only from second , good , but it miss the first problem , is the second select options (the first select option is still enabled) exemple this `$("select > option:first").prop("disabled", "disabled")` it disable only the first select options , i want also the dropdown select options to be disabled the first option

Comment: it fixed the text to appear , now it appear text only from second , good , but it miss the first problem  is : the second select elements (the first select option is still enabled) this `$("select > option:first").prop("disabled", "disabled")` it disable only the first option in first select elements , i want also to be disabled in first option of second select elements . thx